# Vue Typescript filter object of boolean values by array list

Tags: javascript

I have a data list that I want to apply multiple filters on.
The data list contains objects that includes objects with several boolean value like that:

```
dataList: 
[
 {
   id: 1,
   characteristic1: {
     prop1: true,
     prop2: true,
     prop3: false
   },
   characteristic2: {
     prop4: true,
     prop5: false
   }
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   characteristic1: ...
 }
]
```

as filters I have arrays for every characteristic, where the props are string values (added or removed by checkboxes). Like this:

```
characteristic1 = ["prop1", "prop3"]
characteristic2 = ["prop4"]
```

I want to combine the filters with logical AND. Is there any way to filter the list?

As input I have a list as the data list shown above. The output would be something similar, just as a subset from the whole data list (depending on the filter values).

Comment: Can you give sample input and output? It's hard to tell what you're saying.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Vue or typescript? This question is extremely broad, and it's even harder to help you if you mention typescript which apparently has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: it's in a TypeScript context, so if I could use any filter or map method that exists only in ts I thought it might help

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's easier to understand now and you can see a sample input